# Where should I write axios code in react?

Tags: reactjs, post, get, django-rest-framework, axios

I would like to have `axios` work when I click the button.
Then, I write code like this.

**axiosGet.js**

```
showState = () => {

        axios({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/',
            method: 'POST',
        })
        .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    }

...

render() {
     return (
          ...
          <button onClick={this.showState}>Show state</button>
          ...
     )
}
```

and **views.py**

```
class SettingView(viewsets.ModelViewSet) :
    queryset = models.Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer

    def get(self, request) :
        return Response("ok")

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        return Response("ok")
```

No response, no error.

Should I not use axios in ordinary event handler? Or are there any requirements that I must keep in mind when using axios in react?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to make `get` request instead of `post`. you can get the data in `res.data`

```
    axios({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/',
        method: 'get',
    })
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
```

Comment: @Isa4299 really appreciate it, you save me!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/')
    .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Check you api in postman once.

Comment: thanks for reply, I check it and there are data that I want to get but, why didn't they shown in console window?

Answer (score 0):

In-spite of writing axios.get, axios.post and other methods.
what i use to prefer is writing some generic methods which is needed to be called up when ever we need to fire any request to server to get the data from api.

My Sample Code....
created a file as axiosService.js 
and used this file where ever required and simply use the method ApplicationApiHostServ_Axios with all set of parameters required.

`/**
     * ApplicationApiHostServ_Axios will return data in json format...
     * @param {*} url - Path to api...
     * @param {*} method - GET / POST / PUT / DELETE /...
     * @param {*} responseType - Application/json /....
     * @param {*} data - Contains parameters to be passed to api server as request.
     * @param {*} callback - A callback method to be ececuted on success response.
     * @param {*} failCallback - A failCallback method to be ececuted on fail response.
     */
    ApplicationApiHostServ_Axios(url, method, responseType, data, callback, failCallback) {
        let ApplicationApiHost = new ApplicationApiHostServices();
        if (method == 'get') {
            this.ApplicationApiHostServ_AxiosGet(url, responseType, data, callback, failCallback);
        } else if (method == 'post') {
            this.ApplicationApiHostServ_AxiosPost(url, responseType, data, callback, failCallback);
        } else if (method == 'put') {
            this.ApplicationApiHostServ_AxiosPut(url, responseType, data, callback, failCallback);
        } else if (method == 'delete') {
            this.ApplicationApiHostServ_AxiosDelete(url, responseType, data, callback, failCallback);
        }
    }

```
/**
 * ApplicationApiHostServ_AxiosGet will pass a get request, To call an api.
 * @param {*} url - Path to api...
 * @param {*} responseType - Application/json /....
 * @param {*} data - Contains parameters to be passed to api server as request.
 * @param {*} callback - A callback method to be ececuted on success response.
 * @param {*} failCallback - A failCallback method to be ececuted on fail response.
 */
ApplicationApiHostServ_AxiosGet(url, responseType, data, callback, failCallback) {
    axios.get(API_HOST_ADDRESS + url, data)
        .then((response) => {
            if (isFunction(callback))
                callback(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            if (isFunction(failCallback))
                failCallback(error);
            else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')
                console.log(error);
        });
}

/**
* ApplicationApiHostServ_AxiosPost will pass a post request, To call an api.
* @param {*} url - Path to api...
* @param {*} responseType - Application/json /....
* @param {*} data - Contains parameters to be passed to api server as request.
* @param {*} callback - A callback method to be ececuted on success response.
* @param {*} failCallback - A failCallback method to be ececuted on fail response.
*/
ApplicationApiHostServ_AxiosPost(url, responseType, data, callback, failCallback) {
    axios.post(API_HOST_ADDRESS + url, data)
        .then(function (response) {
            if (isFunction(callback))
                callback(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            if (isFunction(failCallback))
                failCallback(error);
            else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')
                console.log(error);
        });
}

/**
* ApplicationApiHostServ_AxiosPut will pass a put request, To call an api.
* @param {*} url - Path to api...
* @param {*} responseType - Application/json /....
* @param {*} data - Contains parameters to be passed to api server as request.
* @param {*} callback - A callback method to be ececuted on success response.
* @param {*} failCallback - A failCallback method to be ececuted on fail response.
*/
ApplicationApiHostServ_AxiosPut(url, responseType, data, callback, failCallback) {
    axios.put(API_HOST_ADDRESS + url, data)
        .then(function (response) {
            if (isFunction(callback))
                callback(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            if (isFunction(failCallback))
                failCallback(error);
            else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')
                console.log(error);
        });
}

/**
* ApplicationApiHostServ_AxiosDelete will pass a delete request, To call an api.
* @param {*} url - Path to api...
* @param {*} responseType - Application/json /....
* @param {*} data - Contains parameters to be passed to api server as request.
* @param {*} callback - A callback method to be ececuted on success response.
* @param {*} failCallback - A failCallback method to be ececuted on fail response.
*/
ApplicationApiHostServ_AxiosDelete(url, responseType, data, callback, failCallback) {
    axios.delete(API_HOST_ADDRESS + url, data)
        .then(function (response) {
            if (isFunction(callback))
                callback(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            if (isFunction(failCallback))
                failCallback(error);
            else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')
                console.log(error);
        });
}`
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, your code is also good to me! I will use it well :)